# Cursor in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use a cursor in oracle to iterate through the GuestID's from the guest table and delete that entry if there is not a corresponding GuestID in the Booking table. This is so that if a guest were to cancel a booking, and that was the only booking they had made, it would remove the guest's details from the guest table.

The procedure if as follows and compiles without any issue:

```
-- Remove a guest from the guest table if no booking exists for their guestID
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RemoveGuest (Selection IN Booking.GuestID%TYPE)
IS
guest_id Guest.GuestID%type;
  CURSOR c_guests is
  SELECT GuestID FROM GUEST;
BEGIN
   OPEN c_guests;
   LOOP
      FETCH c_guests into guest_id;
      IF c_guests%notfound THEN
      DELETE FROM Guest WHERE Guest.GuestID = Selection;
      ELSIF c_guests%found THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Guest ' || Selection || ' is associated with a booking, cannot remove');
  END IF;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c_guests;
END;
/
```

But when I run it, it just hangs like its stuck in an infinite loop:
[image: Anonymous PL/SQL block calling stored procedure and hanging]

Can anyone see where the issue is in this code? I know I could do a trigger also to get the same functionality, and I am more adapt at those than Cursor's, but I just wanted to know why this isn't working?

Comment: There is no `EXIT` in the LOOP, so it will iterate again and again be `%notfound`.

Comment: Where should I place the exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the cursor as an exercise, then you want the cursor to check if the guest exists in the `Booking` table rather than the `Guest` table. When you open the cursor, you don't need to loop since there is only one thing you want to check: was a record found?  If not, delete from `Guest` but in either case, you don't need to look at any more records.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RemoveGuest (Selection IN Booking.GuestID%TYPE)
IS

  guest_id Guest.GuestID%type;

  CURSOR c_bookings_for_guest is
    SELECT GuestID
      FROM Booking
      WHERE GuestID = Selection;

BEGIN

   OPEN c_guests;
   FETCH c_guests into guest_id;
      IF c_guests%notfound THEN
          DELETE FROM Guest WHERE Guest.GuestID = Selection;
      END IF;
   CLOSE c_guests;

END;
```

Without a cursor (syntax may need to be checked):

```
DELETE FROM Guest
  WHERE GuestID = Selection
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Selection FROM Booking WHERE GuestID = Selection) ;
```

Comment: Might I ask, why was it that my anonymous Pl/SQL Block never ended running?

Comment: There was never an exit from the loop.  You did check "if not found" at which point the delete occurred, the end loop was hit, and control was returned to the top of the loop.  It tried to fetch again, was not found, did the delete, got to the end of the loop, and continued on like that in an endless loop.  Similarly if it was found, there was no way to exit.  Somehow you have to explicitly exit.  If you used a "for" cursor loop, you wouldn't need to explicitly exit. Or if you don't loop, like the example above, it will only fetch once.